# Chrome Extension not working with window.open

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window.open

I am writing a chrome extension that needs to modify the html of a popup window that popups with the javascript code something like:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
```

This javascript code is on another website, and I want the extension to run when the popup is opened.

In manifest.json, I have

```
{
    "name":"PresentIT",
    "description":"Connects Google Drive to PresentIT",
    "version":"0.1",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["script.js"]
    } ]
}
```

and script.js I have

```
alert(document.title);
```

When I open a normal webpage I get an alert dialog with the title. However, when I use the javascript code `window.open`, there is no alert.

How can I get the extension to work on the popup page as well?

Thanks

Comment: try including your `window.open` JS file in the `js` array in the manifest.

Comment: the window.open is on another webpage, not part of the extension. sorry if this was unclear

Comment: If it's not the part of the extension how could it just run?

Comment: the user clicks a button, which opens the popup window. I want the extension to run on that newly opened window.

Comment: Have a look at this: [getLastFocused() - chrome.windows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getLastFocused)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui where should I add this?